# Autogenerate sql query from the Graphical calculation view?

Tags: hana

I am trying to test a graphical calculation view in SAP- HANA but I can't edit it due to some production constraints. Is there any way to I Can get the query equivalent of the Calculation view without altering the data at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct calcview - SQL statement conversion available
Why don't you simply copy the calcview in question and modify the copy?

Comment: Hi , I could have done that but the view is in production landscape and I dont have the write rights on the landscape. Stuck !!

Comment: You’ll have to do that in a non-prod environment. Not being able to modify stuff ad hoc is the whole point for having a production system locked down.

Comment: I have the opposite problem - I have the calc view in dev and want to verify it on prod data before asking the data team to replicate in prod...